# how to transform an image with a transformation Matrix in OpenCv?

Tags: c++, opencv, math, graphics, transformation

i want to transform an entire image according to the magnitude of a straight line (y=ax+b) with an angle ( `arcTan(a)` ) this angle should be applied just to the y axis of all the points.

i wanted to use the `warpAffine(...)`

method but what I was able to make work with this method is using points (generally 3) in the image so that `warpAffine(...)` can figure out the angle for itself and transform that part of the image, and that's not what I need because I want to transform the whole image not just a piece.

if there's a way to do this with  `warpAffine(...)` or any other method please let me know

```
cv::Mat t(3,3,CV_64F);
t=0;

t.at<double>(0,0) = 1;    
t.at<double>(1,1) = 1; 
t.at<double>(0,1) = -tan(0.17);    
t.at<double>(2,2) = 1;


cv::Mat dest;
cv::Size size(imgb1.cols,imgb1.rows);
warpAffine(imgb1, dest, t, size, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);

imshow("outputImage.jpg", dest);
```

that's what I could achieve till now, my transformation matrix is like this :

```
1 -tan(angle) 0
0     1       0
0     0       1
```

Comment: *"... but it asks for the destination vertices ..."* - I don't think so, are you sure you checked [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine)?

Comment: thank you, I edited my question. as matter of fact I did gave it a transformation matrix but i couldn't figure out how to represent it using the angle I found

Comment: Can you show us the portion of your code that generates the transformation matrix and then warps the image?

Comment: This is what I achieved till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`warpAffine` takes a 2x3 matrix; just leave off the bottom row of your transform. (I also changed the matrix initialization.) This worked for me:

```
    cv::Mat t(2,3,CV_64F, cvScalar(0.0));

    t.at<double>(0,0) = 1;    
    t.at<double>(1,1) = 1; 
    t.at<double>(0,1) = -tan(0.17);    
//    t.at<double>(2,2) = 1;


    cv::Mat dest;
    cv::Size size(smiley_image.cols,smiley_image.rows);
    warpAffine(smiley_image, dest, t, size, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);

    imshow("outputImage", dest);
```

Here's what I got:

[image: Original Image][image: Output Image]

### Edit

To apply shear in the Y-direction you need to change your transformation matrix to:

```
1               0       0
-tan(angle)     1       0
0               0       1
```

(Actually, the shear transformation is usually `cot(angle)` which is the reciprocal of `tan(angle)`, but if it gives you the results you want, then use it.)

Here's the output image using the new transformation matrix:

[image: Output Image with Y-Shear]

Comment: Thank you for your answer it does work now but what I want to do is to apply this transformation on the Y axis

Comment: @Namine Was this what you wanted?